# Ever any performance different between Java >> and >>> right shift operators?

Tags: java, performance, bit-shift, micro-optimization

Is there ever reason to think the >> (signed) and >>> (unsigned) right bit-shift operators in Java would perform differently? I can't detect any difference on my machine.

This is purely an academic question; it's never going to be the bottleneck I'm sure. I know: it's best to write what you mean foremost; use >> for division by 2, for example.

I assume it comes down to which architectures have which operations implemented as an instruction.

Comment: I think both will be converted to native CPU instructions (logical/arithmetic right-shift) eventually which takes similar cycles.

Comment: No, use `/ 2` for division by 2.

Comment: +1 for making me look up the >>> operator. And don't underestimate the optimization the compiler does. Often optimizing at this level can even make things worse.

Comment: It is not best to use >> for division by 2.  Code is for humans not computers.  The computer translate "/2" to shift anyways.

Comment: Of course, if you are trying to find the average of two positive integers use `>>>`, or you could end up with an integer overflow.

Comment: @Pyrolistical: that said, in addition to what Tom Hawtin said, I'm not sure I want in my team a programmer that doesn't know what >> 1 does...

Comment: @all -- wasn't claiming it's best practice to write ">> 1" for "/ 2", just giving an example of the situation in which you'd have to use >>. javac doesn't translate "/ 2" to ">> 1" but a JIT might.

But it might not, and the difference could matter: this has always been a legit optimization in J2ME-land since lord knows most mobile VMs can hardly tie their shoelaces correctly let alone optimize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.
Your compiler will translate these to bytecode and the JVM will interpret the bytecode for your architecture. I think it is safe to assume that your architecture has an instruction set which includes both operations be done in few clock cycles.

Anyway, there is a difference in the behavior of these operators, so it isn't like you can just interchange them.

Comment: @Tim Bender: +1... In the x86 world, *">> 1"* since the P4 was only one cycle and since the P6 architecture *">> any"* is only one cycle AFAIK.

Comment: I think that was my question: do common architectures implement both as an instruction? And yes like I said this only applies in cases where the behavior is identical (nonnegative integers).